厚労省の資料でSSL-VPNがIPsecよりも安全性が低いとされるのはなぜですか？
SNSで話題になっていたので、「医療情報を取り扱う情報システム・サービスの提供事業者における安全管理ガイドライン」を読んだのですが、そこには次のようにSSL-VPNが原則使用しないこと、といったIPsecほどセキュアではない印象を抱かせることが書かれています。
しかし私の認識では、SSL-VPNも本来的には安全で、たとえばOpenVPNがIPsecを使用したVPNよりも安全ではない、ということはないと考えています。ただ、ガイドラインに明記してある以上、何等かの要因があると思うのですが、そこがわかりませんでした
この資料でSSL-VPNがIPsecよりも安全性が低いとされるのはなぜですか？

SSL-VPN を原則として利用せず、やむを得ず SSL-VPN を利用する場合は、SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドラインに基づき、「クライアント型」での SSL-VPN とすること、そして、IPsec を用いる場合は、IKE を組み合わせる等して、確実にその安全性を確保するように求めている
https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/10904750/000863625.pdf


該当の資料のP.28にある脚注22ですね。他の人にもわかるように全文を引用します。

22 医療情報安全管理ガイドラインでは、専用線、公衆網、閉域 IP 通信網、IPsec を用いた VPN、HTTPS による暗号化等が例示されている。そこでは、HTTPS 接続においては、TLS の設定はサーバ/クライアントともに CRYPTREC が定める「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン（第 2.0 版）平成 30 年 5 月 8 日」（以下、「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン」という。）に規定される最も安全性の高い「高セキュリティ型」に準じた適切な設定を行うこと、また、SSL-VPN を原則として利用せず、やむを得ず SSL-VPN を利用する場合は、SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドラインに基づき、「クライアント型」での SSL-VPN とすること、そして、IPsec を用いる場合は、IKE を組み合わせる等して、確実にその安全性を確保するように求めている。

上記の通り、SSL-VPNよりもIPsecにするよう「求めている」は「医療情報安全管理ガイドライン」であり、「医療情報を取り扱う情報システム・サービスの提供事業者における安全管理ガイドライン」が直接求めているのではありません。つまり、その根拠を確認すべきは「医療情報安全管理ガイドライン」の方であり、それが何であるかはP.2に書いてある通り、正式名称は「医療情報システムの安全管理に関するガイドライン」という資料になります。現在は第6.0版となっているようです。
医療情報システムの安全管理に関するガイドライン　第6.0版（令和5年5月）｜厚生労働省
上記の「システム運用編（Control）」にSSL-VPNに関する記載があります。
P.34

⑥ オープンなネットワークにおいて、IPsec による VPN 接続等を利用せず HTTPS を利用する場合、TLS のプロトコルバージョンを TLS1.3 以上に限定した上で、クライアント証明書を利用した TLS クライアント認証を実施すること。ただしシステム・サービス等の対応が困難な場合
には TLS1.2 の設定によることも可能とする。その際、TLS の設定はサーバ/クライアントともに「TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン 3.0.1 版」に規定される最も安全性水準の高い「高セキュリティ型」に準じた適切な設定を行うこと。なお、SSL-VPN は利用する具体的な方法によっては偽サ
ーバへの対策が不十分なものが含まれる ため、使用する場合には適切な手法の選択及び必要な対策を行うこと。また、ソフトウェア型の IPsec 又は TLS1.2 以上により接続する場合、セッション間の回り込み（正規のルートではないクローズドセッションへのアクセス）等による攻撃
への適切な対策を実施すること。

P.37

オープンなネットワークであるインターネットを用いるサービスとしては、IPsec＋IKE で実現する VPN と SSL-VPN がある。IPsec は、ネットワーク層レベルでの暗号化を図る方法で、インターネット VPN の中でも安全性が高いとされる。SSL-VPN は SSL 技術を利用した VPN でセッション層における暗号化を図るものである。端末側でのアプリケーションが不要など、導入が容易である反面、偽サーバへの対策リスク等がある とされる。

P.39

１３．３．１ ネットワーク回線の暗号化
ネットワーク回線の暗号化については、特にオープンなネットワークを利用する際に求められる。オープンなネットワークでは、盗聴のリスク等があることから、システム運用担当者は、医療情報を医療機関等の外部とやり取りする場合には、TLS の設定を適切に行って、通信するための措置を講じることが求められる。またオープンなネットワークを経由して SSL-VPN を利用する場合には、偽サーバの接続リスクなど も鑑みて、適切な手段を選択することが求められる。

言い方は異なりますが、いずれも偽サーバーへ接続してしまうリスクを懸念しています。偽サーバーへ接続する懸念がない形態、例えば、(特定のサーバー証明書を用いたサーバー以外への接続は拒否するように設定された)専用のクライアントを用いる形式であればIPsecに近い運用形態とみなすことができるので問題ないとされます(Q&AのP.93の「シQ-40」の回答参照)。

前後をよく読むべきです。

医療情報安全管理ガイドラインでは、専用線、公衆網、閉域 IP 通信網、IPsec を用いた VPN、HTTPS による暗号化等が例示されている。そこでは、HTTPS 接続においては、TLS の設定はサーバ/クライアントともに CRYPTREC が定める「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン（第 2.0 版）平成 30 年 5 月 8 日」（以下、「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン」という。）に規定される最も安全性の高い「高セキュリティ型」に準じた適切な設定を行うこと、また、SSL-VPN を原則として利用せず、やむを得ず SSL-VPN を利用する場合は、SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドラインに基づき、「クライアント型」での SSL-VPN とすること、そして、IPsec を用いる場合は、IKE を組み合わせる等して、確実にその安全性を確保するように求めている。

とあり、この記述の根拠は CRYPTREC が定める「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン（第 2.0 版）平成 30 年 5 月 8 日」 に書かれています。


クライアントレス型は、ブラウザさえあればどの端末からでもアクセス可能であり、利便性に優れる一方、TLS との最大の差はグローバル IP をインターネットに公開しているか否か程度の違いといえる。結果として、最初のクライアント認証を TLS サーバが受け持つか、SSL-VPN 装置が受け持つか程度の差でしかなく、VPN というよりも、本質的には TLS と同じものとみるべきである。
On-demand インストール型も、接続時に自動的にインストールされることから、特に利用端末に制限を加えるものではなく、クライアントレス型と大きく異なるわけではない。むしろ、ブラウザでしか使えなかったクライアントレス型を、他のアプリケーションでも利用できるように拡張したという位置づけのものである。
一方、クライアント型は上記の 2 つのタイプとは明らかに異なり、専用のクライアントソフトがインストールされた端末との間でのみアクセスする。つまり、誤って偽サーバに接続することがなく、また内部サーバにアクセスできる端末も厳格に制限できるため、端末に IPsec-VPN ソフトをインストールして構成するモバイル型の IPsec-VPN に近い形での運用形態となる。
機密度の高い情報を扱うのだとすれば、少なくともクライアント型での SSL-VPN を利用すべきである。


つまり、SSL-VPNには３種類あり、クライアントレス型とOn-demand インストール型を推奨せず、クライアント型を推奨するという意味です。

引用しているテキストは省略されていますが、実際には以下のような記載があります。

医療情報安全管理ガイドラインでは、専用線、公衆網、閉域 IP 通信網、IPsec を用いた VPN、HTTPS による暗号化等が例示されている。そこでは、HTTPS 接続においては、TLS の設定はサーバ/クライアントともに CRYPTREC が定める「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン（第 2.0 版）平成 30 年 5 月 8 日」（以下、「SSL/TLS 暗号設定ガイドライン」という。）に規定される最も安全性の高い「高セキュリティ型」に準じた適切な設定を行うこと、

医療情報システムの安全管理に関するガイドライン のページから システム運用編 (PDF) を参照し、"SSL-VPN" で検索すると以下のような記載があります。
「安全性が低い」とは書かれていないものの、適切に選択・設定しないとリスクになりうるので避けた方が良い、と自分は読み取りました。

P.34
なお、SSL-VPN は利用する具体的な方法によっては偽サーバへの対策が不十分なものが含まれるため、使用する場合には適切な手法の選択及び必要な対策を行うこと。また、ソフトウェア型の IPsec 又は TLS1.2 以上により接続する場合、セッション間の回り込み（正規のルートではないクローズドセッションへのアクセス）等による攻撃への適切な対策を実施すること。


P.37
オープンなネットワークであるインターネットを用いるサービスとしては、IPsec＋IKE で実現するVPN と SSL-VPN がある。IPsec は、ネットワーク層レベルでの暗号化を図る方法で、インターネット VPN の中でも安全性が高いとされる。SSL-VPN は SSL 技術を利用した VPN でセッション層における暗号化を図るものである。端末側でのアプリケーションが不要など、導入が容易である反面、偽サーバへの対策リスク等があるとされる。

